# 'Not to be taken as a standard'

Tags: idiom-requests

> 'Not to be taken as a standard to evaluate somebody or something'

Is this correct to say or is there another idiom or saying for it in English?
For example if a team who wasn't expected to lose a friendly and preparatory game, did end up losing, but because it was a friendly game it shouldn't be taken as a standard.. or shouldn't be taken by <sub><sup>*something else*</sup></sub>?

Comment: The question makes me think to these expressions: "Never(always) trust your first impression" and "Apparences may be misleading".

Comment: I've read this question several times and I still don't know what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use the adjective *representative* (formal):

> But because it was a friendly Athletic's performance shouldn't be
>   taken as representative.

Another:

> This should not be taken as a true indicator of Athletic's form at the
>   moment.

And another, to use under- or overperformed:

> Latics underperformed woefully last night.

If you would like to use a metaphor:

> Latics failed to show their true colours last night.

(from [English Club](https://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Idioms/S/show_your_true_colours_show_your_true_colors_695.htm):
*The players showed their true colours when they came back from three goals down to win the match.*)

> All that glitters is not gold.

and Tolkien's reversal:

> All that is golden does not glitter.

(meaning *Not all that is golden glitters*, but sounding far better.)

Answer (score 0):

The most natural way I can think of to say that is:

> He **shouldn't be judged by** last week's game, as he was playing with an undiagnosed broken leg.